# Wrong calculate error between two hours in swift 2

Tags: date, swift2, nscalendar

I have firstHour Example, **12:03**,  secondHour Example, **21:56** ,

End output gives; **9.88**

**88** bigger than **60** minutes this is error, how can i fix it ?  My codes under below.

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    if firstHour != nil && secondHour != nil {

    let dateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: firstHour!, toDate: secondHour!, options: [])
    let seconds : Double = Double(dateComponents.minute)
    let clean : Double = (seconds / 60.0)


    let formattern = NSNumberFormatter()
    formattern.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    let cleando  = formattern.stringFromNumber(clean)!

    print(cleando)

    }

    Output : 9.88
```

Comment: If you want it in hours why not just use `dateComponents.hour`?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @vadian  9.88  is output

Comment: Yes, but what is the expected output? How do you want to fix **what**?

Comment: @vadian 88 is bigger than 60 minute this is wrong calclulate  , must be gives , minute smaller than 60

Comment: For the last time: What is the correct output supposed to be? `9:53`?

Comment: @vadian  must be 21:56 - 12:03   = ?  i dont know , i know only minute must be lower than 60 with true calculate

Comment: @vadian yeah lower than minutes 60 dude

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Swift 2 anymore

Comment: @vadian how can i fix it with math ? seconds gives about 720 integer if we divide it to hours minutes will be true

Comment: I'm out. As long as you don't give information what exactly the expected result is I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide seconds which is in integer format then you will always get answer greater than 60. You need to use `DateComponentsFormatter()` to get difference between time in hours : minute format.

Swift 4 :

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

let timeAtPress = dateFormatter.date(from: "12:03")

let timeAtPress2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "21:56")

let elapsed = timeAtPress2?.timeIntervalSince(timeAtPress!)

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.allowedUnits = [ .minute, .second ]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = [ .pad ]

let formattedDuration = formatter.string(from: elapsed!/60)
print(formattedDuration!) // 9:53
```